# using lines() with 'multiple x entries'

Tags: r, plot, regression

I'm looking for a way to plot a nonlinear regression line on a data set where every value in my vector y is being stored multiple times, so I tried to use something like:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
y <- c(1,4,9,15,25,9,36,25,36,25)
reg4 <- lm( x ~ y + I(y^2) )
plot(x ~ y)
lines(y, predict(reg4), type="l", col="red", lwd=1)
```

this gives https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfWKk.png
[image]

So my question is, is there a way to, let's say, use some sort of mean value for each y entry? Or well just make it a 'continous' line instead of something that branches of into multiple lines/returns to a lower y value at the points where there are multiple 'entries'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem does not come from the ties in the data:
for a given value of `y`, there is only one forecast.
The problem is that the points are not sorted,
so that when you join them, you end up with a tangle of lines.
You can use `order` to reorder the points.

```
plot(
  x ~ y, 
  xlab = "y", ylab = "x"  # Confusing...
)
i <- order(y)
lines( y[i], predict(reg4)[i] )
```

Answer (score 1):

In these cases, it is best to `predict` from the model over the range of the covariate. You do this for say 50 or 100 locations equally spaced over the range of `x`. Increasing or decreasing the number of locations to predict at as needed - more complex responses will need more locations etc. Doing this also solves the spaghetti plot issue as the `newdata` supplied will be in the order of `x`

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
y <- c(1,4,9,15,25,9,36,25,36,25)
reg4 <- lm( x ~ y + I(y^2) )
## predictions
pred <- data.frame(y = seq(min(y), max(y), length = 100))
pred <- transform(pred, x = predict(reg4, newdata = pred))
## plot
plot(x ~ y)
lines(x ~ y, data = pred, type = "l", col = "red", lwd = 1)
```

[image]